# Using window functions to calculate engine hours in a timeseries data in PostGres

Tags: postgresql, time-series, gps, analytics

I am building a vehicle tracking system, and storing the data as a time-series data (continuous stream of time-based data updates).

There is a need to run analytics to calculate distance, engine hours and movement hours among other things. I need help understanding the best way to calculate this (without running a loop function)

Engine hours and movement hours are calculated as the time difference between engine on/off and speed more than 1 / less than 1 respectively.

[Table DDL](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r_H6SNhiKD-_-rUi2_pDW2dqD20Nsy9T/view?usp=drive_link)
[Sample Data 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DM-QMZP3xiF7HOcfwNCc_IMIYDxyGnPs/view?usp=drive_link)
[Sample Data 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GsIDS66Q58mU3sUF_6lUX_IuPNIkVoRB/view?usp=drive_link)

I am currently fetch all the records from the database and calculating the required data by iterating through all the datasets, this is time consumning and is utilizing a lot of cpu.

Comment: You have to describe your requirement in more detail. Also, add your table definition and your sample data not via hyperlinks, but as formatted text in the question.

Comment: Please provide text data as *text*. No images. Provide a *minimal* example for your question. Trim columns irrelevant to the question. Always disclose your version of Postgres. And make your desired result unambiguously clear.

Comment: This appears to be a homework assignment (a similar post appeared a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77595756/seeking-guidance-on-optimizing-engine-hours-calculation-from-iot-data). Many in the SO community are happy to offer assistance; however, one should make a serious attempt at the code prior to asking for help. Including your code in the post will make it easier for others to provide guidance.